# Use AquaticPrime Framework with AppleScriptObjC

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, aquaticprime, applescript-objc

how would I go about using the [AquaticPrime Framework](http://aquaticmac.com/) in AppleScriptObjC?

Comment: In what context? Are you looking to automate their Developer application? Is this for an application you have written that you want to automate?

Comment: I want to use the AquaticPrime Licensing Framework in my application so that people can register and all. Just like the demo application on the AquaticPrime Github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very broad topic, but essentially, you will need to implement Applescript automation in your application, and possibly implement it in the Aquatic framework you download. [Apple's Applescript documentation](http://developer.apple.com/applescript/) is very far-reaching and covers more topics than I think can be managed in a single answer.

Comment: How would I call "isLicensed" of one of the AquaticPrime classes?

There's an AppleScript-Studio example of using AquaticPrime here: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32422 but how would I do exactly what he did, but in ASOC?

Comment: What have you tried so far? ASOC has simple and clear rules on how to call Cocoa methods, but there is a fair amount of hooking up that needs to be done in order to do so. There are a number of tutorials out there, in addition to a book all about ASOC and using it to create applications.